# How far to go with spring bronze weatherstripping on wood double-hung windows

Tags: windows, weatherstripping

I've been restoring windows in my small 1925 colonial over the past year. Most of the windows haven't seen any maintenance in decades, but on the flip side, nothing horrible has been done to completely ruin them. The top sashes have been fixed into place. Not ideal, but to safe myself some extra work as I'm working on a ton of other projects, I'm leaving that way as I restore the lower sash and jambs. Effectively, they're single-hung. When restoring, I'm scraping all paint, sanding, priming, and painting the jambs, sill, and lower sash and replacing the sash cords. In some cases, I'm re-glazing.

My question relates to the weatherstripping as I am reinstalling the lower sash after restoration. I've been putting spring bronze in the jambs of the lower sash, and on the meeting rail of the upper sash. However, I'm not getting a great seal between the lower sash and the sill, partially because the bottoms of many of the sashes were damaged and the angles are no longer as precise as they once were.

I've seen a lot of different configurations of how people install spring bronze in double-hung (or single-hung) windows. What do you recommend for weatherstripping between the sill and the lower sash? I thought I'd add more spring bronze, but thought again that might look silly. Is the spring bronze I've put on the meeting rail excessive?

Comment: All the rental units I've seen, there's *nothing* there and you just get drafts.

Comment: Is your reason to maintain all original design for a historical register? I ask because in some cases changed design is a violation and replacing the woodwork is the only way to maintain the qualification. If you are just trying to save a few $ and completing a diy there are some goretex rope seals that can help seal without changing the look and some historical zones allow this to preserve the wood work.

Comment: I can't speak for the historical aspect, but there may not be room for spring bronze on the meeting rail between the sashes. If not, like on my 1929 Craftsman, you can use a 3/4" - 1" wide strip of felt. I've also seen, like Ed said, rope set into a groove. I'd be cautious of spring bronze on the side jambs wearing a groove in the sashes over time; I'll suggest a softer seal there. While you're fully restoring your sashes, can you recut or sand the bottom edge to meet the sill better, maybe inset a wider, more forgiving seal than bronze strip?